# How to add my own Custom Resolution in Adaptive bitrate in Ant Media

Tags: video, streaming, webrtc

When I check the Adaptive bit-rate settings I see that there are predefined resolution in [Ant Media](https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/) which is good, but I want to add one more Custom resolution in the settings , but I do not see any option to do that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.